# Can we provide an stack of IP's to the Open Vswitch to pick the IP?

Tags: networking, configuration, kvm-virtualization, openvswitch, virtual-network

I have started learning virtualization using KVM hypervisor and trying to set-up virtual cluster on the host machine.However from the tutorials on the internet states that the VM connected to OVS bridge port get the IP from the host network DHCP server only(Guest VM will behave like it is on host network only).

However I would like to know if we can provide different IP-stack to be used by OVS to assign IP to guest VMs ?

PS: DHCP server of my network assign IP's to machines on network only if their MAC is registered.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by **IP-stack** you mean IP address space / IP subnet.

Yes, you can do that. You would have to set up a separate network for the VMs, which is not bridged to the Host's normal network.

You also need to set up a dummy interface in the Host VM, which is then assigned to the same bridge that is used by the VMs.

Finally, if you want to be able to get addresses for the VMs via DHCP, you need to set up a DHCP server somewhere, usually the Host VM. This DHCP server would be assigned to the VM network.

Comment: ya, you got it right. But now i am left with few more questions, may be sound naive but i would like to know-- 1.)what do u mean by 'dummy interface'?is it different from eth0 ? 2.)Does kvm allow us to create separate network ?3.)Do i need to execute every point stated by you in the answer ?

Comment: Would be great if you can provide pictorial representation of what you have stated in answer as i am just a student and trying my hands first time on networking since the last week. WILL BE really really THANKFUL TO YOU :)

Comment: It is best for you to look up articles on the subjects mentioned in my answer. There is a lot of information on these subjects on the Internet, and it is pointless to copy the information here.